# Page walk cycles effect on total execution cycles

Tags: linux, profiling, perf, cpu-cycles

I have measured `cycles` and `dTLB_load_misses.walk_active` for an application using *perf* tool. I executed the application two times. First time in isolation and the second with a single thread memory-bound app running on another core (same socket). I noticed that `cycles` is almost steady between executions but `dTLB_load_misses.walk_active` increases sometimes up to 50%.

My understanding is that `cycles` shows the total CPU cycles the application used throughout its execution. Also, `dTLB_load_misses.walk_active` is the total cycles that page miss handler (PMH) actively walked the page table. If this is correct, then, how it is possible that PMH cycles increase significantly but total `cycles` remains steady or even slightly decrease in some cases?

The process running in isolation:

```
Performance counter stats for './wc ../../data/wc/300MB_1M_Keys.txt -p 10':
                                 
      186904181366      cycles                                                        (66.45%)
       13002068556      dTLB_load_misses.walk_active                                     (66.78%)
         176249928      dTLB-loads-misses         #    0.69% of all dTLB cache hits   (66.81%)
       25500563014      dTLB-loads                                                    (66.57%)
         469338866      cache-misses              #   55.629 % of all cache refs      (66.73%)
         843696674      cache-references                                              (66.64%)

       9.257579987 seconds time elapsed
```

The process runs beside a single thread memory-bound process:

```
Performance counter stats for './wc ../../data/wc/300MB_1M_Keys.txt -p 10':

      184567329729      cycles                                                        (66.50%)
       14006882920      dTLB_load_misses.walk_active                                     (66.61%)
         229413645      dTLB-loads-misses         #    0.89% of all dTLB cache hits   (66.82%)
       25693682363      dTLB-loads                                                    (66.78%)
         472148745      cache-misses              #   55.619 % of all cache refs      (66.68%)
         848898094      cache-references                                              (66.61%)

       9.243842709 seconds time elapsed
```

**EDIT**:

Transparent huge pages, THP defrag, numa_balancing, and turbo boost are disabled.

My CPU is Intel Skylake, Xeon Gold 6142.

Comment: Sounds like TLB prefetching (and out-of-order exec to get demand misses started early) are doing their jobs, getting page walks started soon enough to not end up stalling the critical path and not costing lost cycles of real work.  Your TLB-miss rate for loads was quite low, so maybe most of the page-walks are triggered by stores?  And that's only the L1dTLB; some of those dTLB misses would be L2TLB hits (aka STLB), not needing a page walk.  `dtlb_load_misses.miss_causes_a_walk` will show you how many demand loads actually triggered a new page-walk to start.

Comment: What CPU are you testing on?  Skylake for example has two independent page-walk units, so up to two page walks can be working in the background.  Overly aggressive TLB prefetch might be doing some unneeded page walks, but as long as it's not evicting entries you need, it's fine.  Run-to-run differences could be due to differences in transparent-hugepage usage, especially if you aren't using `madvise(MADV_HUGE)` to hint the kernel to defrag physical memory to free up contiguous pages for a 2M page.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Thanks for your nice info. I didn't know page-walks happens in backgrounds via two page-walk units. I did some syscall tracing using strace and noticed that in the second case (with interference), `futex` overhead increases substantially (27%). Do you think it's possible that part of this page-walk cycles is due to the `futex` execution time increment?

Comment: @PeterCordes Might not be related to this question, but is there any way to circumvent prefetching to see if it is the prefetching effect?

Comment: You can disable HW data prefetching system-wide, with an MSR write.  (You need root, and have that kernel module enabled for MSR access).  But data-prefetch works on physical addresses, I don't know if there's a separate config bit for TLB prefetch ("next page" prefetch), but it'd be worth googling.  Branch mispredicts leading to speculative execution of loads / stores on bad addresses can also start page walks.

Comment: As far as extra futex overhead, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Like fraction of your program's time spent in futex?  With competition from a memory-bound thread on the same physical core, yeah that could compete with page walks, making some TLB misses more expensive, for cases where that matters.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the futex overhead, your assumption is correct. I exactly meant more fraction of the program is spent in futex when interference presents. And when that increases, the page-walk cycles increase too. I was wondering if there is any causality or correlation between number of futex calls and page-walk cycles?! @PeterCordes

Comment: No obvious reason why futex specifically would be slowed down more than other parts of your program by contention for memory access, although it might be doing a memory barrier in user-space that has to wait for the store buffer to drain.  (Which will take longer in that case.)  That's just a random guess, and I expect the details depend on what your program is doing, which you've said nothing about, beyond the fact that it doesn't access L3 cache very often, but when it does the miss rate is 55% for loads.